# Unknown null pointer exception-java

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I am trying to execute the following code.

```
    Date date=new Date();
    //System.out.println("date "+date.getTime());
    List<User> d=sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
    List<String> onlineUsers=null;
    for(User u:d){
        System.out.println(((date.getTime()/1000)-(u.getLastUpdated().getTime()/1000)));
        long s=((date.getTime()/1000)-(u.getLastUpdated().getTime()/1000));
        long j=120;
        System.out.println(u.getUsername());
        if(s<=j){
            onlineUsers.add(u.getUsername());
        }
    }
```

Even though the output is coming out to be less than 120 its not even entering into the if loop. Why is it so? Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPE is thrown if the code in your if statement gets executed because `onlineUsers` is `null`. Perhaps you should try initializing `onlineUsers`:

```
List<String> onlineUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize this List type

```
List<String> onlineUsers=null;
```

Do this it will do the work for you

```
List<String> onlineUsers=new ArrayList<String>();
```